# How to reset a result state to its initial value in react hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I already have a form with additional cost and a total cost input.
I want to add the value of additional cost to my total cost on its change event
but when I remove the value of that additional cost input I want the total cost to have its initial state value

```
<input type="text" onChange={((e) => setTotalCost(totalCost + e.target.value))} placeholder="additional cost" />

<div>totalcost: {totalCost}</div>`
```

This is my state:

```
const [totalCost, setTotalCost] = useState(0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it by checking if the additional cost has a value of not like:

```
onChange={(e => {
   if(e.target.value){
     setTotalCost(totalCost + e.target.value);
   }else setTotalCost(0);
})}
```

If you are getting initial state from an API request then you can store it in state:

```
const [initialState, setInitialState] = useState();

//Do the API call to set initialState

onChange={(e => {
   if(e.target.value){
     setTotalCost(totalCost + e.target.value);
   }else setTotalCost(initialState);
})}
```

Comment: but initial state is not 0 I receive it from response of server

Comment: Updated Answer.

Answer (score 0):

`const clearState = () => { setTotalCost(0); };`

Call the above function where you want to initialize the state.

Comment: but initial state is not 0 I receive it from response of server

Comment: In my opinion, you should not add totalcost and target value right away, but use useEffect to get the accumulated totalcost when the totalcost state changes.